# A little help finding the complexity of time and and complexity of space

Tags: complexity-theory

```
int f2(int n)
{    
    int x, y, z = 0, i;

    for(x = n, i = 0; i < n; i ++, x *= n)
    {
        y = x;
        while (y > 1)
        { 
            y /= 3;
            z += y;
        }
    }
return z;
}
```

I get confused by the first loop and my problem is that I can’t figure out how many times the loop is executed and how `x` influences 
the code in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's:

log<sub>3</sub>(n) + log<sub>3</sub>(n<sup>2</sup>) + ... + log<sub>3</sub>(n<sup>n</sup>) = log<sub>3</sub>(n)n(n+1)/2

in short term:

```
n^2log(n)
```

Comment: so is it $theta$($log(n)*n^2$) in the short term?

Comment: does log(3n) belong to the family of log(n)?

Comment: is the complexity of space here O(1)? because I dont see arrays or strings

Comment: I reformatted using sub-/superscripts for legibility, but I do not know what your last expression is meant to be, so I left that to you.